# Finding representations of (nonholonomic) Jet groups

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, fiber-bundles

For an n-dimensional smooth manifold $M$, We can consider the bundle of 1-jets $J^1 M$ to be a $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ bundle over $M$. Representations of this group are straightforward. (Note by $J^1$ I mean $J^{1} _{n}$ always)

I am interested in finding representations of higher nonholonomic jet groups.  For the second order nonholonomic jet bundle we have
$$\tilde{J}^2 M = J^1 J^1 M$$  which is a $J^1 Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ bundle.  How then to find representations of this group (or more generally representations of $J^1 G$ where $G \subset Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$).

In reading *The differential Geometry of Frame bundles*, Cordero, Dodson, De Leon (pg 19) say that:

> Let $FM(M,\pi_{m},Gl(n,\mathbb{R}))$ denote the frame bundle of the
> differentiable manifold $M$,
> $$J_{n}^{1}FM(J_{n}^{1}M,\pi_{M}^{1},J_{n}^{1}Gl(n,\mathbb{R}))$$ the
> induced $J_{n}^{1}Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$-principal bundle, and let
> $$FJ_{n}^{1}M(J_{n}^{1}M,\pi_{J_{n}^{1}M},Gl(n+n^{2},\mathbb{R}))$$ be the
> frame bundle of $J_{n}^{1}M$.
>
> Theorem 2.1.2 There exists a canonical injective homomorphism of
> principal bundles
>
> $$j_{M}:J_{n}^{1}FM\rightarrow FJ_{n}^{1}M$$
>
> over the identity of $J_{n}^{1}M$, with associated Lie group
> homomorphism
>
> $$j_{n}:J_{n}^{1}Gl(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow Gl(n+n^{2},\mathbb{R})$$
>
> Theorem 2.1.3 Let $\pi_{m}:FM\rightarrow M$ and $\pi_{FM}:FFM\rightarrow
>  FM$ be the frame bundle of $M$ and $FM$ respectively. Then, $j_{M}$ induces a
> bundle homomorphism of $J_{n}^{1}FM|_{FM}$ into $FFM$ with respect to
> $j_{n}$, i.e.
>
> $$j_{M}(X\cdot Y)=j_{M}(X)\cdot j_{n}(Y)$$
>
> for $X\in J_{n}^{1}FM|_{FM}$ and $Y\in J_{n}^{1}Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$, and the
> following diagram commutes

$$\begin{array}{ccccc} J_{n}^{1}FM|_{FM} & \rightarrow & j_{M} &
 \rightarrow & FFM\\ \downarrow &  &  &  & \downarrow\\ \pi_{M}^{1} & 
 &  &  & \pi_{FM}\\ \downarrow &  &  &  & \downarrow\\ FM & \rightarrow
 & 1_{FM} & \rightarrow & FM \end{array}$$

Where they note that $FJ^1 M|_{FM}$, the restriction of $F J^1 M$ to $FM$ is canonically isomorphic to $FFM$, the frame bundle of the frame bundle.

Does this embedding of $J^1 Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ in $Gl(n+n^2 , \mathbb{R})$ then form a representation?  I don't quite get the restriction to $FM$ part.  Is this homomorphism injective (i.e. is this a faithful representation?)
Anyone who could straighten this out would be much appreciated.